# Reading a tuple from a pandas dataframes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

This can be a silly question but I have a .csv formed by a column of string and a column of tuples. The problem is that when I read the second column I read it as a column of string instead of a column of tuples.

I have a .csv archive with the next dataframe:

```
Paint,RGB Value
Abaddon Black ,"(0, 0, 0)"
Administratum Grey ,"(152, 156, 148)"
Ahriman Blue ,"(0, 112, 138)"
Alaitoc Blue ,"(47, 79, 133)"
```

That dataframe has the first column formed by the names of the paints and the second column formed by the tuple of the rgb values of each paint.

The problem is that when I open the .csv files and read the second column I don't read that column as a list of tuple, I read this as a list of string. Here is my code when i want to read the fisrt RGB value 8in that case the value of the Red) of the first paint (It have to be 0):

```py
import pandas as pd



datos = pd.read_csv('Pinturas GW.csv', header = 0)

num = datos['Valor RGB']

print(num[0][0])
```

But this print only '(', that´s why I think that my program read de column as a list of string instead of a list of tuples. Thanks you!!!

Comment: It appears to work fine with: `df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/x.csv')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a silly question at all! You can use the `ast.literal_eval` function. This function safely evaluates an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. For example, you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df =  pd.read_csv('Pinturas GW.csv') # load your file
df["RGB Value"] = df["RGB Value"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
print(df["RGB Value"][0][0]) # prints 0
```